# Unknown column 'table.column' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, glassfish

I have updated one of my tables to include the column `canttouchthis` using the MySQL Workbench.
From the MySQL Workbench there is no problem writing sql against the column `canttouchthis`. But, in my code I get the following error on any instance of said column, but the remained of the columns work just fine, such as `groups.id`

`Unknown column 'groups.canttouchthis' in 'field list'`

Even a simple select statement like the following doesn't work:

```
try {
    String sql = "SELECT  groups.canttouchthis FROM  groups";
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        data.addProperty("got_data", rs.getLong(groups.canttouchthis));
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    StackTrace.print(ex);
}
```

I have tried reseting my Java Servlet Container server to no avail

Comment: remove `groups.` just use `canttouchthis` or use an alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I was passing the wrong database connection to this point.
Thanks for your vigilance, I would delete this question if I could.

Comment: Even these questions can be useful - please remember to accept this answer as correct as soon as you are able.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new alias like SELECT  gp.canttouchthis AS ctt FROM  groups as gp  after user "ctt" in while loop